# Get each variable from class in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an interpreter that reads

```
variable1: 2
variable2: 400
variable3: 31
```

from a text file, and initializes the variables on runtime. using eval() and Regular Expressions

```
class Rules{
    getSegmentArgs_string(sgmnt, scope)
    {
        let argarray = new Array;
        let vardeclaration;
        for(let i=0; i<this.rules[sgmnt].length; i++)
        {
            let regexp = /(\w+): ([0-9\.]+)/g;
            for (const match of this.rules[sgmnt][i].matchAll(regexp)) {
                vardeclaration = (scope+match[1].toString() + " = "+match[2].toString()+";");
                argarray[i] = vardeclaration;
            }
        }
        return argarray;
    }
    setSegment(sgmnt)
    {
        this.segment = sgmnt;
    }
    init()
    {
        this.defaultvars = this.getSegmentArgs_string(this.segment,"this.")
        for(let i=0; i<this.defaultvars.length; i++)
        {
            eval(this.defaultvars[i]);
        }
        delete(this.rules);
        delete(this.defaultvars);
        delete(this.segment);
    }
    constructor() {
        this.rules = this.dump();
    }
}
let rules = new Rules;
rules.setSegment(3);
rules.init();
```

However, I can not understand how to access these initialized variables in a for loop that dumps each variable's name, as well as its' value

```
for (const variables in rules)
{
          console.log({variales});
          console.log({variables}.value);
}
```

I'm capable of accessing the value when doing

```
console.log(rules.variables1,rules.variables2,rules.variables3)
```

but due to the nature of the task, I need to loop through all variables without naming them in code.

Comment: what does your `env` look like? If it is a JS Object, you can access the keys by `Object.keys`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) gives you the key of the object properties. You have to access the value with the key

```
for (const key in rules)
{
      console.log(key, rules[key]);
}
```